# Basic inheritance - need a line of code explained

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public int getPassengerCount() {
    int counter = 0;
    for (TrainCar vogn : YOLO) {
        if (vogn.getClass() == PassengerCar.class) {
            counter += ((PassengerCar) vogn).getPassengerCount(); //This line
        }   
    } return counter;
}
```

In this code I'm traversing through an `Arraylist` of `TrainCars`.

Two types of `TrainCars`; `PassengerCar` or `CargoCar`. So first I check if the wagon is an instance of the class `PassengerCar` (and I'm aware of `instanceof`, but I assume this way works aswell?), and if it is, I need to grab the field containing the number of passengers, i.e. the method `getPassengerCount()`.

In the marked line, however, there is code I do not fully understand. I realise I can not write `vogn.getPassengerCount()`, because the "vogn" may be either a `CargoCar` or a `PassengerCar`. Then again, I do it after the if-clause, so it shouldn't result in an error. So why can I not? Why is this the only way that works, and what does it do? I have never seen such a syntax, and I honestly have no clue what to Google. Any advice? :-)

Comment: You're *casting* `vogn` to `PassengerCar`.

Comment: Does `TrainCar` have a method `getPassengerCount()`?

Comment: TrainCar has a method for returning the weight of an empty cart. PassengerCar and CargoCar extend TrainCar, while the last class, Locomotive, is the class where I'm currently a little stumped. :-)

Comment: Your design mixes types that should never be mixed. I don't remember what it's called, but it's like putting (or forcing) an internal identifier inside a class to distinguish between two possible sub-types, when it should ***be*** two sub types, and treated that way by all code. In other words, distinguishing between passenger and non-passenger cars should not be done in each function, but rather at a much more fundamental level in your design. This function should never have to know about--or need to filter for--non-passenger cars.

Comment: @aliteralmind Good advice. I was thinking `TrainCar` might just have a `getPassengerCount` method that may return `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods, at compile time, are resolved based on the static/declared type of the expression they are invoked on.

As you've stated, the `getPassengerCount()` method only exists on the type `PassengerCar`. As such, you can only invoke the method on an expression that resolves to a `PassengerCar` instance. You can do that by casting your variable that is of type `TrainCar` to the more specific `PassengerCar`.

```
((PassengerCar) vogn)
```

Do this only if you know that `vogn` is referencing a `PassengerCar`, otherwise you would get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Ahh! `((PassengerCar) vogn)` is _casting_? Then I know what to Google. Thank you all so much! :-) (edit: seems I don't have to Google. Thank you all for the responses - apparently I can't upvote yet, but thank you anyway! :))

Answer (score 1):

(assuming `TrainCar` does not have a `getPassengerCount()` method)

Well, the assumptions says it all. `vogn` holds a reference to an instance of `TrainCar` and not `PassengerCar`. Since `TrainCar`s don't have that method, you will need to downcast it to a child class that has it. That's why the cast is required, even though you, the programmer, now that, at that point, you have an instance of `PassengerCar`.

Answer (score 1):

`counter += ((PassengerCar) vogn).getPassengerCount(); //This line`

Hmmm... let's see.

If the `vogn` is an instance of `PassengerCar`, then it adds the number of passengers in that car to the total number of passengers.

So, it is necessary to *cast* the `vogn` object to its subclass to access the method `getPassengerCount()` (which probably isn't present in `TrainCar`).

A better way would be:

```
public int getPassengerCount() {
    int counter = 0;
    for (TrainCar vogn : YOLO) {
        if (vogn instanceof PassengerCar) { //This is easier :-)
            counter += ((PassengerCar) vogn).getPassengerCount();
        }   
    } return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is more a of "why Java reacts this way?" than "is that normal?".
Think about it another way, what if your condition was like

```
if (vogn instanceof PassengerClass || a == b)
```

Then if a == b and vogn is not an instance of PassengerClass, you would call a method of something that could be a different class than PassengerClass.
The fact that there could be many statements in a condition seems to be a good reason of why the syntax you're talking about is dangerous.